# What is the correlation between "Hash" (Method ID) & "Name"

Tags: solidity, uniswap, function, create, method

I was checking Etherscan and come across a deployed contract (Create contract), but the method id was **0x60a06040**.

I then used https://openchain.xyz/signatures?query=0x60a06040 and found out that the name is "**rugPullAll((uint240),(bytes4),int88[],bytes4,int136)**"

what is going on here ?

Comment: It's a bad joke by someone :) Fun fact - 0x60806040 is another typical byte sequence at the start of a contract, and for a while it was showing in Etherscan as a function called "atInversebrah": https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x60806040

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Method ID (not a hash of a function name that'd be in the deployed contract) even though Etherscan shows it as Method in the UI.

And that it shows as `rugPullAll` and even other ones if you check other resources like [4byte.directory](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x60a06040) is a mere coincedence and is relatively common in causing confusion.

`0x60a06040` is a common starting point of the bytecode of a contract:

- `0x60` is the PUSH1 opcode which pushes the next byte onto the stack.
- `0xa0` is the byte pushed onto the stack by the first PUSH1.
- `0x60` is another PUSH1 opcode.
- `0x40` is the byte pushed onto the stack by the second PUSH1.

This is essentially a sequence initializing memory for the contract. It's injected by the Solidity compiler as part of the contract creation and initialization process. Nothing in the high level Solidity code of the contract itself is directly specified to result in `0x60a06040`.